# Solving limit without L'hopital $\lim_{x\to0} \left(\frac{\frac{xe^x}{e^x-1}-1}{x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to solve this limit using **transformations** & **common limits** but I've been unable to:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\left( \frac{\frac{xe^x}{e^x-1}-1}{x}\right)$$

> This limit simplifies to $1/2$ using L'Hôpital's rule but I had to use it 3 times in order to get the result. (I'm trying to prove that the function is differentiable at $x=0$.)

So if anyone is able to solve it using **transformations** only without **L'hopital** I would be grateful.

Thanks for your time and stay safe...

Comment: I wonder why L'Hopital is still teached, given that you never are allowed to use it.

Comment: I wonder why too..., most likely in order to check your results

Comment: Are you allowed to use Taylor polynomials?

Comment: No, I'm not allowed but if you can solve it using Taylor polynomials it would be interesting and informative

Comment: The "difficult" bit is $$
\frac{x}{{e^x  - 1}} = \frac{x}{{x + \frac{{x^2 }}{2} + o(x^2 )}} = \frac{1}{{1 + \frac{x}{2} + o(x)}} = 1 - \left( {\frac{x}{2} + o(x )} \right) + \mathcal{O}\left( {\left( {\frac{x}{2} + o(x)} \right)^2 } \right) \\ = 1 - \frac{x}{2} + o(x ).
$$

Comment: Using common limits you can see that desired limit equals the limit of $$\frac{xe^x-e^x+1}{x^2}=\frac{e^x-1}{x}-\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$$ Clearly you need to apply L'Hospital's Rule (once) or Taylor on second term and you are done. Avoid repeated applications of L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: I don't know why you had to apply L'Hopital's Theorem thrice but anyways, we have:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{xe^x-e^x+1}{xe^x-x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{xe^x}{e^x+xe^x-1} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x}{\frac{e^x-1}{x}+e^x}$$

Observe that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1$ (this is just the derivative of $e^x$ at $x = 0$). Obviously, $e^x \to 1$ as $x \to 0$. Hence, the limit above is just $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: If you had to use L'Hôpital's rule that often, maybe you were [being efficient](http://spikedmath.com/585.html).

Comment: It was in my test today, so I didn't want to get stuck on a limit

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with Taylor polynomials if you take $y:=1-e^{-x}$, so the limit is$$\lim_{y\to0}\left(\frac1y+\frac{1}{\ln(1-y)}\right)=\lim_{y\to0}\frac1y\left(1-\frac{1}{1-y/2+o(y)}\right)=-\frac12.$$

Answer (score 2):

Note

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left( \frac{\frac{xe^x}{e^x-1}-1}{x}\right)
 =\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac1{1-e^{-x}}-\frac1x\right)
= \lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac1x +\frac12 +O(x)-\frac1x\right)=\frac12
$$